# Facebook API: Scraping Problems as well as unknown Hebrew Unicode

Tags: python, facebook, api, unicode

I created a facebook app to integrate with my python scripts.
I have permissions to get notifications and messages from user.

The problem is when I get notification, I doesn't scrape it well:

```
notification of Somebody is {u'title_text': u'Texas HoldEm Poker: Hurry! CLAIM your 
$25,000 FREE CHIPS now!'}
```

as you can see, the "{u'title_text': u' ...... "}" doesn't belong there.
How can I get only the text message inside?

the second problem is when I'm trying to get message in hebrew, it looks like this:

```
{u'title_text': u'\u200e\u200e\u05d7\u05df \u05d1\u05dc\u05d7\u05e0\u05e1\u200e posted 
on Danie's\'s timeline\u200e: "Have a lot of good luck"'}
```

the "\u200e\u200e\u05d7\u05df \u05d1\u05dc\u05d7\u05e0\u05e1\u200e" is a name of someone in hebrew, how can I encode it to look perfect as the name itself?

Thank you.

Edit: I found that the unicode is "utf-8" and I need to add "u" before the string
but what if my program gets a string .. how do I add the "u" to the existing string?
Thanks.

Edit: Updated Code:

```
def insertNewNotification(notification_list, owner):

for notification in notification_list:
    notification = repr(notification['title_text'])
    notification = str(notification)
    notification = unicode(notification, 'unicode-escape')
    notification = notification.encode("UTF-8").decode("UTF-8")
    print "notification of " + owner + " is " + notification
    response = json.load(urllib.urlopen((url + "add_notification&message=" + notification + "&owner=" + owner).encode("UTF-8")))
return 1
```

Comment: remove everything except `u = notification['title_text']; print u`. What is `type(u)`?

Comment: Key_error if I do: repr(notification['title_text']) It gives me the text in unicode with u" "

Comment: Worked !!! Woha ... Thank you so much! I'll go ahead and learn better python now from the documentions, thank you so much, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{u'title_text': u'Texas HoldEm Poker: Hurry! CLAIM your 
$25,000 FREE CHIPS now!'}` is a representation (`repr()`) of a dictionary with Unicode key and value.

`u""` is Unicode literal in Python. You type `u` only inside Python source code.

You probably has the following code somewhere `print "notification of Somebody is", data`

You should use `print data['title_text']` instead.

Learn the difference between:

```
>>> s = u"\u2324"
>>> s
u'\u2324'
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x8c\xa4'
>>> print repr(s)
u'\u2324'
>>> print s
⌤
```

Comment: when I use ['title_text'] It gave me: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: the above assumes that `data` is a dictionary. If it a string; you need to figure out where does it come from and avoid doing `str(data)` upstream

Comment: Great, works like a charm the only problem is when I print it gave me u"text Here", I converted it to STR, how do I remove the u and the " ", thanks!

Comment: My bad, when I do convert to str from unicode it gave me: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 40-45: ordinal not in range(128), what should I do to remove the unicode prefix?

Comment: @Somebody: there is no Unicode prefix in memory. There are only Unicode strings (look at the `s` Unicode string above). What do you want to do with them: print to your terminal, save to a file, database, etc?

Comment: when I print it I have: u"Noar Zy Zichron-yaaqov invited you to" I don't wanna have the 'u' prefix and the " " afterwards, is there anyway to remove them .. instant using .replace()

Comment: Look at `print s` above. Do you see `u''` in the output?

Comment: [link](http://gyazo.com/754289cecb27c5d6916b147a6e3f478b) Look at the image, its still show u" " before ..

Comment: @Somebody: Open python console and try to play with a Unicode string: call `repr(s)`, `str(s)`, `print(s)`, `print s.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)`, `print([s])`, `type(s)` etc until you understand the difference between an object and its string representation.

Comment: @Somebody: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22627298/edit) and include the code in it. **Do not call `str`.**

Comment: Updated, any problems in my code? I'll try to play around with it

Comment: @Somebody: `repr`, `str`, etc are **for debugging**. You shouldn't leave them in your production code